# Useful, answered question deleted, can it be restored?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

A user has deleted a question after I answered it. This question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798644/overriding-in-prolog

I found the question interesting (I upvoted it) and the answer taught me something, so I think it would be useful to others. I'm not sure why the user deleted the question (or how, since I thought you couldn't if the answer had upvotes) and would like to see it restored. What's going on here?

Comment: The answer doesn't have upvotes.

Comment: @RobertLongson I see, I didn't know about that condition. Still, I think one hour isn't really that long for Prolog questions, which can take a day or more to get answered. It might still be useful for others to see it and they might upvote my answer or provide a better one.

Comment: You didn't? But you wrote that in this question... i.e. (or how, since I thought you couldn't if the answer had upvotes)

Comment: @RobertLongson I seem to have gotten myself mixed up about which one needed the upvote!